# Web Bluetooth send text from phone to browser

Tags: ios, google-chrome, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I've been doing a lot of reading and research on Web Bluetooth.

I just want to send some text from a BLE Server (in this case a web app running on iOS WebBLE app)...and have the text appear on another web app running on Chrome on my Mac.

I just want a textarea and a send button for the Server and a dynamically updatable span on the client.

Seems like all tutorials assume Server is some kind of peripheral (monitor, light bulb, etc)..and that you just have to write Client code to interact with it.

Is it possible to do this? Seems like it should be simple. Thanks

**I guess I'm asking how to turn desktop Chrome into peripheral device using Web BT**

How can I get my Mac browser to advertise using Web BT?

Comment: I found https://github.com/noble/bleno and https://beaufortfrancois.github.io/sandbox/web-bluetooth/generator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web Bluetooth API does not include APIs for acting in the peripheral role. A page using the API can only take on the role of the central.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Happen to know of any other way to do this on a Mac? Looks like Bleno had dependency issues and hasn't been supported in years. There are other Python wrappers, but no luck yet. I'm just doing this as practice before I get an esp32 shipped to me